# Можно ли убрать анимацию в QPushButton?

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qpushbutton

Хотелось бы убрать анимацию нажатия кнопки в PyQT5, т.к. при нажатии не очень подходит к интерфейсу.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('data/images/icon_1.ico'))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.fon_1, self.folder_path = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget), QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.by, self.history = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget), QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.settings, self.about = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget), QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.interfacePyQT()

    def interfacePyQT(self):
        self.setObjectName("Main_body")
        self.resize(800, 450)
        self.setFixedSize(800, 450)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.fon_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 450))
        if (read_file('data/settings', 'theme') == 'White'):
            self.fon_1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("data/images/main_1.jpg"))
        else:
            self.fon_1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("data/images/main_1_dark.jpg"))
        self.fon_1.setObjectName("fon_1")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("data/font/AcromThin.ttf")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.folder_path.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(125, 324, 241, 25))
        self.folder_path.setFont(font)
        self.folder_path.setStyleSheet("font-size: 17px; color: rgba(76, 195, 253, 0.7);")
        if (len(list(read_file('data/settings', 'saves'))) >= 28):
            text, text_copy = list(read_file('data/settings', 'saves')), []
            for i in range(0, len(text), +1):
                if (27 > i): text_copy.append(text[i])
                elif (27 <= i < 30): text_copy.append('.')
            text = ''
            for element in text_copy:
                text += element
            self.folder_path.setText(text)
        else: self.folder_path.setText(read_file('data/settings', 'saves'))
        self.folder_path.setObjectName("folder_path")
        self.by.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(740, 382, 47, 61))
        self.by.setFont(font)
        self.by.setStyleSheet("font-size: 17px; color: rgba(76, 195, 253, 0.7);")
        self.by.setText('me')
        self.by.setObjectName("by")
        self.history.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 80, 291, 291))
        self.history.setStyleSheet('color: white; font-size: 12px')
        self.history.setFont(font)
        self.history.setText(str(history()))
        self.history.setObjectName("history")
        self.settings.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 120, 171, 31))
        self.settings.setFlat(True)
        self.settings.setObjectName("settings")
        self.settings.clicked.connect(self.buttonSettings_onClick)
        self.about.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 180, 161, 41))
        self.about.clicked.connect(self.About)
        self.about.setFlat(True)
        self.about.setObjectName("about")
        self.retranslateUi()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)
        self.show()

    def retranslateUi(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Main_body"))

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if (e.key() == Qt.Key_F): self.buttonTranslate_onClick()
        elif (e.key() == Qt.Key_R): self.theme()
        elif (e.key() == Qt.Key_Escape): self.close()

    def theme(self):
        if (read_file('data/settings', 'theme') == 'White'):
            self.fon_1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("data/images/main_1_dark.jpg"))
            read_file('data/settings', 'theme', 'Dark')
        else:
            self.fon_1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("data/images/main_1.jpg"))
            read_file('data/settings', 'theme', 'White')

    @pyqtSlot()
    def buttonTranslate_onClick(self):
        self.translate_screen = translate()
        self.translate_screen.show()
        self.close()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def buttonSettings_onClick(self):
        self.settings_screen = settings_1() if (read_file('data/settings', 'settings_body') == '1') else settings_2()
        self.settings_screen.show()
        self.close()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def About(self):
        self.input_screen = start_input()
        self.input_screen.show()
        self.close()
```

Я пытался найти способ убрать аниацию кнопки в интернете, но где-то говорят просто почитать документацию (в документации не понял как убрать), где-то ответ не работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и объясните лучше, что вы хотите сделать. А также вы должны запомнить: "НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения."

Comment: `self.settings, self.about = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget), QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)`. Я не знаю как еще понятнее объяснить, нужно просто убрать анимацию кнопки...

Comment: тоесть сделать кнопку ненажимемой?

Comment: Нет, проблемы не в этом. Я знаю как сделать кнопку не нажимаемой, мне нужно просто убрать анимацию кнопки, но при этом кнопка должна реагировать. Допустим при нажатии, открывается новое окно, но при этом без анимации кнопки